# Error: overloaded function with no contextual type information - SetWindowLong()

Tags: windows

http://friendpaste.com/2FgBfMlNYM3IfBDuNol9i1

I get the error on line 62. The enumCW callback function simply sets the lvmHwnd variable.
The dll is injected into the processes that i'm trying to subclass.

Any help on this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the #include "main.h" after the include of Windows.h. SetWindowLong() is a macro define for either an ANSI or UNICODE variant, and I wonder if something brought in by main.h is interfering with that.